# How does this gawk command work?

Tags: awk, gawk

I am trying to understand gawk in shell scripting.

How does this command work?

```
 gawk -vN="$N"
```

and this split based on what

```
 n=patsplit($0,a,/\<\w*\>/,s)
```

and this

```
PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
```

How does it work?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Comment: @grebneke i need to know how these commands  work just?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first command passes an argument to `gawk`. The argument is `N` and the value assigned to `N` is the value of the bash variable `$N`.
- The second command splits the awk variable `$0` into strings based on the regex `/\<\w*\>/`. It returns the number of strings that it was able to split. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions. The regex is comopsed of `\<` (start of word boundary), `\w` (word constituent), `\>` (end of word boundary). See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators
- The third command is a special feature of `gawk` version 4.1. That is used to traverse arrays in specific order (in a `for` loop).. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array

Comment: the third command where it stored the value?,and what the meaning of a in the second command?

Comment: @john `a` is the array of strings. See manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions

Comment: @john What do you mean by `stored value`?

Comment: where it stored the array?

Comment: Which array do you mean?

Comment: Yes, do you mean the from the `patsplit()` function?

Comment: is this the array sorted_in?

Comment: It assign a value to the associative array `PROCINFO` with key `"sorted_in"` such that in a later `for` loop for traversing an associative array, the keys are traversed in specific order..

Comment: but where it take the input array?

Comment: Which array do you mean?

Comment: where is the input of this command PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"?

Comment: since it should the take the array after we convert it to small letter.

Comment: Do you mean: the function `@val_num_desc`?

Comment: Currently there is no input.. We just assign a reference to the function `@val_num_desc` to the array `PROCINFO` such that `awk` later can use this when scanning a given array, for instance the array `a` after the `patsplit()` function..